# Can't append_entry FieldList in Flask-wtf more than once

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form with flask-wtf for uploading images, also file field can be
multiple fields.

my form:

```
class ComposeForm(Form):
    attachment = FieldList(FileField(_('file')), _('attachment'))
    add_upload = SubmitField(_('Add upload'))
```

my view:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.add_upload.data:
        form.attachment.append_entry()
        return render_template('mailbox/compose.html', form=form)
    else:
        form.attachment.append_entry()
```

my template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
     {% for field in form %}
         {{field}}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form, `append_entry` doesn't work. It only appends one more field.
Again I click on `add_upload`, but after refresh I have again only one field (not two).

How can I fix this? There is no error, I think, because enctype wtform forgets how many fields I have to add more.

Comment: What is the error message you receive when you try to do `append_entry`

Comment: @tkone there is no error, in simple form remember count of fields but in multipart every time only appended form has one field

Comment: Well how does '`append_entry` not work? What happens when you execute that function? What is the result of your code?

Comment: @tkone add more description in edit

Comment: i still don't see what happens when you run this code.  what are you expecting and what are you getting?  your call to `append_entry()`?  what is appending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call to `append_entry` is missing it's data.

From the [Documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#field-enclosures):

> append_entry([data])
>
> Create a new entry with optional default data.
>
> Entries added in this way will not receive formdata however, and can only receive object data.

If you're trying to get the data that was submitted on the form, you might try to use `pop_entry`.  Or at least doing some debugging and seeing what `form.attachment.entries` looks like.  Does it contain values? What happens when you iterate through those values?